# Active Record Validation Errors displayed outside of a form in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When [Active Record Validation Errors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views) are displayed outside of a form, they look like this at the top of the browser:

```
{
"title"=>["is too long (maximum is 25 characters)"],
"picture"=>["can't be blank"],
"tag_list"=>["5 tags maximum"]
}
```

How can I turn this array into something more ascetic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easy in ruby.

```
error_hash = {
    "title"=>["is too long (maximum is 25 characters)"],
    "picture"=>["can't be blank"],
    "tag_list"=>["5 tags maximum"]
}

req_hash = {}
error_hash.each do |_hash|
  req_hash[_hash[0]] = _hash[1][0]
end

p req_hash
#=> {"title"=>"is too long (maximum is 25 characters)", "picture"=>"can't be blank", "tag_list"=>"5 tags maximum"}
```

Even though there is many and concise way to do.

Hope this help you!